# Where is the quote “received many bounces on the [Internet]” from?

Tags: story-identification, quotes

I’ve read a lot of science fiction books in the last two years. I’ve become very interested in a quote I can’t remember where I found:

> It received many bounces on the [Internet].

(It referred to an Internet-like communication platform, but I can't be sure what they called it.)

It referred to what we would call “retweets” today. I’ve spent days trying to find the quote.

I thought it could have been from the Orson Scott Cards’ Enderverse, Peter F. Hamiltion’s Commonwealth universe, or possibly Michael Flynn’s Firestar series. (It's definitely from a book available through Audible.)

Comment: is [internet] the word from the quote, or are you modifying it?

Comment: @JackBNimble it refers to an Internet like communication platform, but I can't be sure what they called it.

Comment: Is that from a book that predates the internet as we know it?

Comment: @Gilles, it offered an alternative take on it, at least. Not too far away from what we have today. Only the terminology was off—but very interestingly so.

Comment: I don't know the SF story which possesses the term you want but the term "bounce" in communications comes from radio.  It can mean bouncing the signal off the ionosphere, the moon, or other objects.  It's a means of transmitting signal beyond the line of sight and generically means sending & receiving over long distances:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%E2%80%93Moon%E2%80%93Earth_communication

Because this term has been in use a long time, the SF story you are looking for could quite old.

Comment: Been a long time since I read it, but Heinliens's "Friday" has an internet and when the characters use it I think they refer to answers to queries as bounces.

Comment: How about Vernor Vinge's _A Fire Upon the Deep_?  In those books, there was an interstellar network very similar to our Internet.